# Are there plans to update the Yahoo logo on the login screen?

Tags: feature-request, login

The Yahoo logo used to look like this:

[image: Old Yahoo logo]
<sub>(source: [ranklogos.com](http://www.ranklogos.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/yahoo_logo.jpg))</sub>

But only recently, the logo was changed to this:

[image: New Yahoo logo]
<sub>(source: [amsterdamprinting.com](http://blog.amsterdamprinting.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/yahoo-new.png))</sub>

However, the login button continues to use the old logo:

[image]

Are there plans to change it to the new logo anytime soon?

Comment: I mean, wow. The new logo is so amazing! It has a DIFFERENT FONT! And... wait, that's all.

Comment: @Doorknob Are you thinking that the logo change was very slight that there is no use in doing this?

Comment: No, just commenting on the pointlessness of the whole big deal about the logo change. :) I agree that it should be updated, I upvoted your post.

Comment: shouldn't this be a bug and not a feature-request? for new users that are not familiar with the old yahoo logo, it may seem that the login is not trustworthy...

Comment: @Doorknob Actually, I now have a downvote.

Comment: I'm hoping that if we procrastinate long enough, serif fonts will make a comeback...

Comment: @Shog9 The sans-serif fonts are supplanting the serif fonts at lots of places now. One example: Microsoft Word now uses Calibri instead of Times New Roman as the default body font.

Comment: AFAIR serif fonts was introduced to improve readability of low-quality prints, back in the printing press times. Sans-serif everywhere makes me sad - computer screens are not that great yet. I believe in comeback, too!

Comment: @Molot We now have high-res screens replacing the low-res ones, so I guess that sans serif fonts are slightly ahead of their time.

Comment: @gparyani have you seen [this comparison](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q86C51Qrt0s)? I think they are *way* ahead of time.

Comment: @Mołot a logo does not need readability. it doesn't even have to have letters...

Comment: How come everybody has forgotten about Google? Should I post a separate bug (I don't think so)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Yahoo login was only possible with OpenID, which has been discontinued.