# Is there any way to get notified of someone posting a duplicate of your own question?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions, notifications

I've been known for asking [really interesting questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/215114/gparyani?tab=questions) here on Meta. I know about the "Linked" bar at the right side of the question that inludes all of the linked as well as backlinked questions and duplicate questions. My question is: does the Stack Exchange notification system send me a notification if someone else asks a question and it gets marked as a duplicate of one of my questions?

Comment: I wonder though, if there is a way to query for these in the data explorer?

Comment: *"I want to know if and when someone does that."* - But why? Why is that information *so* useful to you that you need a *notification* for it? I doubt many, if any, users would find that notification useful.

Comment: @animuson As I said in the question, I tend to ask interesting questions. By that, I mean that I ask questions that are, at times, ahead of their time (like [Will Stack Exchange support SPDY?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197001/will-stack-exchange-support-spdy)) and questions that will likely be asked again (like [Change Yahoo logo on login screen to new logo](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197610/change-yahoo-logo-on-login-screen-to-new-logo)). I want to know, for my own research purposes, how duplicates of questions like these are asked and how often they are asked.

Comment: I'd suggest adding it to the [list of notifications for favorite questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53580), so you can just star to follow them, but they still haven't even implemented notifications for those either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The system does not send you such a notification.

I suspect the first people to ask the really simple questions that get repeated ad infinitum would disagree with this as a feature request quite vehemently.